# How to validate angular material table?

Tags: angular6, angular-material-6, angular-material-table

I'm having a hard time to validate angular material table. I need to disable the save button till all fields are filled in the mat-table.

I tried to do this with forms, both template driven and reactive ways, but failed.

This is the html code

```
<mat-card class="card">
  <mat-card-title fxLayout.gt-xs="row" fxLayout.xs="columin">
    <h3>Product Groups Editor</h3>
  </mat-card-title>
  <mat-card-content>
    <div class="data-container">
      <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns sticky: true"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="englishName">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header class="table-header">English Name</th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
            <input [disabled]="!element.active" [(ngModel)]="element.englishName" value="{{element.englishName}}">
          </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="color">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="table-header">Color</th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
            <input [disabled]="!element.active" [(colorPicker)]="element.color" [style.background]="element.color" />
          </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="level">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header class="table-header">Level</th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
              <mat-select placeholder="Level" [disabled]="!element.active" [(ngModel)]="element.groupLevel">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let eachLevel of allGroupLevel" [value]="eachLevel.groupLevelId">
                  {{eachLevel.name}}
                </mat-option>
              </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>
          </td>
        </ng-container>

      </table>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button id="addButton" (click)="addGroup()" mat-raised-button color="primary">
        <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>Add Group
      </button>
      <button id="saveButton" (click)="saveGroups()" mat-raised-button color="primary">
        <mat-icon>save</mat-icon>Save Groups
      </button>
    </div>
  </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

I will be much thankful if someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert with Angular, and may not have done this the best way. However, I have done it and got it working, so here's how:

In the Component module, create a FormControl for each control in the HTML. For the table, I used an array of FormGroups, each FormGroup having the controls for a single row of the table. These controls and groups are created based on the MatTableDataSource contents.

My example code below uses a master object with a couple of properties, and an array of detail objects, each of which has  3 properties.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators, FormBuilder }   from '@angular/forms';
import { MatTableDataSource }  from '@angular/material';

class Detail {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  value: number;
};

class Master {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  details: Detail[];
};

@Component({
  selector: 'app-master-detail',
  templateUrl: './master-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./master-detail.component.css']
})
export class MasterDetailComponent implements OnInit {

columnsToDisplay = ['detail_id', 'detail_name', 'detail_value'];

master: Master;
form: FormGroup;
dataSource = new MatTableDataSource([]);
minMasterId = 1;
maxMasterId = 100;
minDetailId = 1;
maxDetailId = 10;

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

ngOnInit() {

  // Add some code here to get your source data and load it into this.master
  // ...
  // I've added some dummy data to show the principle.
  this.master = {
    id: 1,
    name: "myMaster",
    details: [
      { id: 1, name: "myDetail1", value: 100 },
      { id: 2, name: "myDetail2", value: 200 }
    ]
  };

  // Create the FormControls for the Master.
  this.form = this.fb.group({
      id:      new FormControl(this.master.id, [Validators.required, Validators.min(this.minMasterId), Validators.max(this.maxMasterId)]),
      name:    new FormControl(this.master.name, [Validators.required]),
      details: this.fb.array([])
    });

  // Load the detail objects into the MatTableDataSource.
  this.dataSource.data = this.master.details;

  // For each detail object:
  // 1) Create a FormGroup containing FormControls for all the properties.
  // 2) Add the FormGroup into an array.
  let detailsArray = this.fb.array([]);
  this.dataSource.data.forEach(detail => {
    let formGroupForThisDetail = this.fb.group({
      detail_id:    new FormControl(detail.id,      [Validators.required, Validators.min(this.minDetailId), Validators.max(this.maxDetailId)]),
      detail_name:  new FormControl(detail.name,    [Validators.required]),
      detail_value: new FormControl(detail.value,   [Validators.required, Validators.min(0)]),
    });
    detailsArray.push(formGroupForThisDetail);
  });

  // Add the finished array onto the top-level form.
  this.form.setControl('details', detailsArray);
}
```

So, now there is a FormControl for every property of every object in the table, and the FormControl includes the validators appropriate to each property.

These FormControls are referenced in the HTML as follows:

```
<div class="title">
  <h2>View/Edit Master - {{name.value}}</h2>
</div>

<mat-form-field class="master-field-id">
  <input matInput placeholder="Master ID" formControlName="id" type="number" min="{{minMasterId}}" max="{{maxMasterId}}">
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field class="master-field-name">
  <input matInput placeholder="Name" formControlName="name">
</mat-form-field>

<mat-table formArrayName="details" [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="detail_id">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ID </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let detail; let rowIndex=index" [formGroupName]="rowIndex">
      <input matInput placeholder="ID" type="number" formControlName="detail_id" min="{{minDetailId}}"
        max="{{maxDetailId}}">
    </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="detail_name">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let detail; let rowIndex=index" [formGroupName]="rowIndex">
      <input matInput placeholder="Name" formControlName="detail_name">
    </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="detail_value">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Value </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let detail; let rowIndex=index" [formGroupName]="rowIndex">
      <input matInput placeholder="Value" type="number" formControlName="detail_value" min="0">
    </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
  <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnsToDisplay"></mat-header-row>
  <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columnsToDisplay"></mat-row>
</mat-table>

<button class="mat-raised-button mat-primary" [disabled]="form.invalid" (click)="onSave()">Save</button>
```

The "Save" button at the bottom of the form will change its state depending on all the validators on all the properties (i.e. if ANY validator is INVALID then the form as a whole is invalid and the button is disabled).

You need to implement "onSave()" somewhere to actually do the saving.